# Which Angular version is suitable for Share point framework (spfx)

Tags: angular, sharepoint

Hello I am an new trainee working on the share point framework and also new to Angular So, i need to learn both so asking a simple question that which Angular version is suitable for share point framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use all versions of Angular. In this case SharePoint page plays role of place where you can host Angular, SharePoint lists play role of database, and you can use SharePoint Rest Api to access data of this lists. Pretty good way to use SharePoint - this works and feels much better than SharePoint out of box.

Comment: Thanks for your response but may be I am not clear with my question. I just want to know that the tutorial like Hello World Webpart available on Microsoft developer site then other samples available on git for an instance Oliver's spfx-40-fantastic (https://github.com/OlivierCC/spfx-40-fantastics) in which angular version are they built on?